# SSH using old password after user password change

Tags: ssh, debian

We have run into weird issue where after SSH-ing into two different machines using password (both running Debian 5.0), changing password with `passwd`, logging out, new password is being rejected as incorrect. We can still connect using old password.

When trying to change the password again:

1. using old password as current - we get `passwd: Authentication failure`
2. using new password as current and new: `Password unchanged`
3. using new password as current and changing it to another one: the password is changed yet isn't recognized as valid SSH password when logging in.

We don't have root access there and `sudo` has been limited to few commands.

What could be the reason of such behavior?

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain the reason?

Comment: I really don't know why this got downvoted or close-voted. I'm voting Leave Open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you asked, I guess you do know what to do: ask the admin to check if the configuration of the pam modules are correct. He/she may have to reset your failed login counter as well.

Comment: We haven't received any response of admins since Monday, in the meantime we have switched to public key authentication. 

One thing I've just noticed was lack of /etc/pam.d/sshd on both of the machines.

Comment: At last we have a response from admins: according to them the machines are using chroots and password change hasn't been propagated outside. While I'm not sure if that was the real culprit, they've also added sshd to /etc/pam.d/ and now things seem to work. Marking this as correct answer then.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, that the admin of the machine made ssh authenticate against an LDAP or kerberos database.

You might check the common-* files in /etc/pam.d

Comment: I've checked the files, there are no LDAP nor kerberos modules used there. I've compared ```common-*``` files with those from other machines, there were no differences.